# Convert delimited string to array enum using generics in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, enums, .net-2.0

I need to convert a comma delimited string into an array of enum types within a generic class.

The problem is I need to create an array based on the generic T.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testIt = new TestIt<TestValues[]>();
        TestValues[] converted = testIt.Convert("Pizza,Sub");
    }
}

public class TestIt<T> 
{
    public T Convert(string delimitedValues)
    {
        var valueType = typeof(T);
        var elementType = valueType;
        if (!valueType.IsArray)
        {
            throw new Exception("T is not an array");
        }

        if (valueType.HasElementType)
        {
            elementType = valueType.GetElementType();
        }

        var elements = delimitedValues.Split(',');
        foreach (var elementValue in elements)
        {
            var newElement = Enum.Parse(elementType, elementValue.Trim(), true);
            // not sure what I can do with the element here
        }

    }
}

public enum TestValues
{
    Unknown,
    Pizza,
    Sub,
    Burger
}
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?  I'm stumped!

I've tried creating an object array of the enum type, but can't seem to convert it to T.

Please keep in mind, this is **.Net Framwork 2.0** so my toolbox is limited.

Thanks for any ideas anyone can provide.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `var` for everything, that's going to make it a wreck to debug - apart from that, what about this solution doesn't work?

Comment: @EBrown `var` doesn't make debugging any more difficult.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's a matter of opinion, in **this** situation it may have minimal impact, but if he is in the habit of using `var` everywhere he's going to run into odd issues in the future, where it is uncertain why the solution did not work. I.e. Type-mismatches, etc. Yes, it's great for anonymous types, but definitely should **not** be a default go-to or catch-all as he is using it.

Comment: @EBrown you're confusing `var` with `dynamic`.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're missing the point: `var` is intended to provide support for anonymous types, not a catch-all: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx another good one: http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/336 Yes, `var` has many, great use cases. But overuse, just like overuse of anything, is bad. That's my point. Regardless of how it works, using something as such excessively can result in ugly, poor code, I implore you to define the merit of not informing someone of the potential problems/caveats of using such a practice.

Comment: @EBrown oh, my. I though the anti-var-camp died out already. You're linking to four year old (!) blog posts. As it nowadays is being used, it most certainly isn't reserved for anonymous types. Try to browse some SO Q&As or open source repositories. It also doesn't cause such big woes as you claim it to. OP's usage of `var` here is the perfect example of why and when you _should_ use it: `var foo = new SomeType<Bar>()`, `var bar = typeof(T)`, `foreach (var foo in bar)`: small-scoped, where typing the full type name would only be a burden and not provide any profit.

Comment: @CodeCaster Please, tell me, looking at the last for-each block in his code, what type is `newElement` specifically, and what properties/values/fields/methods/etc. are attached to it? You can't, not by looking at that line specifically. You have to move up to where `elementType` is declared and then further to `valueType`, and only then is it clear that `newElement` will be the type of T. This is my point, that you completely miss: yes, `var` has certain *great* uses, however, as I said before, it should not be a catch-all type. Because as it stands alone, `newElement` is indeterminable to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code: you can use `Array.CreateInstance` as you already know the array length (`elements.Length` after the `Split()`), then call `Convert.ChangeType()` to be able to convert `Array` to `T`:

```
public T Convert(string delimitedValues)
{
    var valueType = typeof(T);
    var elementType = valueType;
    if (!valueType.IsArray)
    {
        throw new Exception("T is not an array");
    }

    if (valueType.HasElementType)
    {
        elementType = valueType.GetElementType();
    }

    var elements = delimitedValues.Split(',');

    var arrayToReturn = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, elements.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++ )
    {
        var newElement = Enum.Parse(elementType, elements[i].Trim(), true);
        arrayToReturn.SetValue(newElement, i);
    }

    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(arrayToReturn, valueType);
}
```

Comment: That worked!  Didn't think about using Array.CreateInstance.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Try this class:

```
public class TestIt
{
    public static T[] Convert<T>(string delimitedValues)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (delimitedValues == string.Empty)
        {
            return new T[0];
        }

        string[] parts = delimitedValues.Split(',');
        T[] converted = Array.ConvertAll(parts, x => (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), x));
        return converted;
    }
}
```

By convention you use `T` as the generic parameter instead of `T[]`

Use it like:

```
TestValues[] values = TestIt.Convert<TestValues>("Unknown,Pizza");
```

You can do it even with one less cast:

```
public static T[] Convert<T>(string delimitedValues) where T : struct
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (delimitedValues == string.Empty)
    {
        return new T[0];
    }

    string[] parts = delimitedValues.Split(',');
    T[] converted = new T[parts.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!Enum.TryParse(parts[i], out converted[i]))
        {
            throw new FormatException(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    return converted;
}
```

If you want, you can even have a version that will return `T?[]` (so an array of nullable enums)

```
public static T?[] ConvertNullable<T>(string delimitedValues) where T : struct
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (delimitedValues == string.Empty)
    {
        return new T[0];
    }

    string[] parts = delimitedValues.Split(',');
    T?[] converted = new T?[parts.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (parts[i] == string.Empty)
        {
            continue;
        }

        T value;

        if (!Enum.TryParse(parts[i], out value))
        {
            throw new FormatException(parts[i]);
        }

        converted[i] = value;
    }

    return converted;
}
```

Use it like;

```
TestValues?[] values = TestIt.ConvertNullable<TestValues>(",Unknown,,Pizza,");
```

Note that this last version doesn't skip "invalid" values, it still throws on them. Simply it transforms `string.Empty` elements to `null`. Sadly there is a problem: if you `ConvertNullable<TestValues>(string.Empty)` it will return a `TestValues[0]`, but that string could even be converted to `TestValues[1] { null }`.

Now, if you really want a pizza with everything:

```
public static class EnumSplitter
{
    public static T[] Convert<T>(string delimitedValues) where T : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (delimitedValues == string.Empty)
        {
            return new T[0];
        }

        string[] parts = delimitedValues.Split(',');
        T[] converted = new T[parts.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Enum.TryParse(parts[i], out converted[i]))
            {
                throw new FormatException(parts[i]);
            }
        }

        return converted;
    }

    public static TArray ConvertArray<TArray>(string delimitedValues) where TArray : IList
    {
        return MethodCache<TArray>.Convert(delimitedValues);
    }

    public static T?[] ConvertNullable<T>(string delimitedValues) where T : struct
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (delimitedValues == string.Empty)
        {
            return new T?[0];
        }

        string[] parts = delimitedValues.Split(',');
        T?[] converted = new T?[parts.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (parts[i] == string.Empty)
            {
                continue;
            }

            T value;

            if (!Enum.TryParse(parts[i], out value))
            {
                throw new FormatException(parts[i]);
            }

            converted[i] = value;
        }

        return converted;
    }

    public static TArray ConvertNullableArray<TArray>(string delimitedValues) where TArray : IList
    {
        return MethodCache<TArray>.Convert(delimitedValues);
    }

    private static class MethodCache<TArray> where TArray : IList
    {
        public static readonly Func<string, TArray> Convert;

        static MethodCache()
        {
            if (!typeof(TArray).IsArray)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("TArray");
            }

            Type element = typeof(TArray).GetElementType();
            Type element2 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(element);

            if (element2 == null)
            {
                Convert = (Func<string, TArray>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, TArray>), typeof(EnumSplitter).GetMethod("Convert").MakeGenericMethod(element));
            }
            else
            {
                Convert = (Func<string, TArray>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, TArray>), typeof(EnumSplitter).GetMethod("ConvertNullable").MakeGenericMethod(element2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the `MethodCache<>` class to cache the reflection call to the "right" `Convert<>` method.

Uses:

```
TestValues[] arr1 = EnumSplitter.Convert<TestValues>("Unknown,Pizza");
TestValues?[] arr2 = EnumSplitter.ConvertNullable<TestValues>("Unknown,,Pizza,");
TestValues[] arr3 = EnumSplitter.ConvertArray<TestValues[]>("Unknown,Pizza");
TestValues?[] arr4 = EnumSplitter.ConvertNullableArray<TestValues?[]>("Unknown,,Pizza,");
```

Comment: Nice! (BTW, I think you can omit the `<T>` from `if (!Enum.TryParse<T>(parts[i], ...`)

Comment: I agree everything would be easier if I could use T[], but in this scenario, I can't change the type of the generic.  This is a sample that I created from a part of a much bigger solution.  However, I do like your approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T[] ToEnumsArray<T>(this string stringValuesWithDelimeter) where T : struct
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValuesWithDelimeter))
        {
            var arr = stringValuesWithDelimeter.Split(',');
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                if (Enum.TryParse(item, true, out T enumResult))
                {
                    result.Add(enumResult);
                }
            }
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```